# app slowing down due to image load issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, grand-central-dispatch

I am having problem with the loading of content in the app, I see that the data is fetched by the app but the images take lot of time to load, is there any possibility to load images afterwords. The code is below:

```
NSDictionary *dict=[discussionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UIImageView *avatarimage = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:4];
NSString *photoStrn=[dict objectForKey:@"photo"];

 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
                   NSString *u=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@",photoStrn];
                   NSURL *imageURL=[NSURL URLWithString:u];
                   NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
                   dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                   UIImage *dpImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                   if (dpImage==nil)
                   {
                     dpImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"profileImage.png"];
                   }
                   avatarimage.image = dpImage;

        });
```

If you want more details I will provide :)

Comment: see this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786018/loading-an-image-into-uiimage-asynchronously

Comment: Take a look a this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15270523/2106940

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [GCD](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) for doing this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
     for (NSDictionary *dic in discussionArray)
     {
        NSString *photoStr=[dic objectForKey:@"photo"];
        NSString * photoString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@",photoStr];
        UIImage *dpImage =  [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:photoString]]];
        if (dpImage==nil)
        {
            dpImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"profileImage.png"];
        }
     }
});
```

Comment: I tried this approach the pages are loading fast :), though there is one problem that is on scrolling the app changes avatar images and reloads the images. I think I have made some error, I am updating the code above.

Comment: @JamesMitchee I guess that you are using a tableView and that you forgot the reset the image back to its default when reusing a cell.

Answer (score 0):

Get [SDWebImage Here](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) and add that in your project and include

> UIImageView+WebCache.h

in class implementation file

```
UIImageView *imag=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
[imag setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[jsonarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"imgurl"]]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon@2x.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:imag];
[imag release];
```

SDWebImage will be more useful for loading images from URL.

Hope this Helps !!!

Answer (score 0):

James,

With this line,

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:photoString]]]
```

you make a synchronous network call on the main thread. The current thread will hang untile the network call is complete.

The solution would be to do an asynchronous network call. The [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) library provides a great category to load images asynchronously : [UIImageView+AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/UIImageView+AFNetworking.h).