# How to increase the UITableview Performance and Fast Scrolling?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, scroll, uitabbarcontroller

I have created an custom cell in UITableview and its work fine for simulator as well as device.In device scroll the tableview its lagging how to increase the performance as well as fast scrolling in UITableview.

Comment: What's the count of dataSource array? If huge, I would suggest you to use pagination so that you can load next set of data when user scrolls to bottom.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352479/tricks-for-improving-iphone-uitableview-scrolling-performance

Answer (score 0):

To increase the performance of the table you can load the table asynchronously . Refer the my following answer :

[how to do multi-threading to load the image faster to tableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15270395/how-to-do-multi-threading-to-load-the-image-faster-to-tableview/15270523#15270523)